# saving and reading back numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have ndarray like this. I am writing it to a dataframe, saving as a pickle, reading that pickle, and then creating new array again. Why does `np.array_equal(my_array2,X_train)` return false? i tried to debug and have written some code to understand the problem but having a hard time

How should I change the code so that both arrays match?

```
X_train=array([[" I I want to know how much s it thank you"],
       [" press any key to connect P Thank you Too <unk> I "]],
      dtype='<U97064')
X_train


X_train[0]
#array([[' I I want to know how much s it thank you'],
       [' press any key to connect P Thank you Too <unk> I ']],
      dtype='<U97064')


df = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns = ['Column_A'])


df.to_pickle('df.pkl')
df2 = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')

my_array2= df2['Column_A'].to_numpy(dtype='<U97064')

np.array_equal(my_array2[0],X_train[0])
#false

np.array_equal(my_array2,X_train)
#false
```

type of arrays match

```
print (type(my_array2))
print (type(X_train))

#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

but individual members dont match

```
#not sure why datatype of individual elements is different
print (type(my_array2[0]))
print (type(X_train[0]))
#<class 'numpy.str_'>
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

X_train.dtype
#dtype('<U97064')


type(X_train.dtype)
#numpy.dtype
```

Comment: I don't the pickle has anything to do with it.  `pandas` has changed your array in `df`.  A dataframe is 2d, and a column is 1d.  Compare the shape of your `X_train` and `df[column].to_numpy()`.  You can save numpy arrays without involving pandas.

Comment: could you show the complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,
`X_train[0]` is itself an array while `my_array2[0]` is a string.

```
print(X_train[0])
>>array([' I I want to know how much s it thank you'], dtype='<U97064')
print(my_array2[0])
>>' I I want to know how much s it thank you'
```

If you want `my_array2` to be a numpy array of shape `(2,1)` the shape same as `X_train`, add `.reshape(2,1)`.

```
my_array2= df2['Column_A'].to_numpy(dtype='<U97064').reshape(2,1)

print(np.array_equal(my_array2[0],X_train[0]))
>>true

print(np.array_equal(my_array2,X_train))
>>true
```

Comment: do I need to replace 2 in `.reshape(2,1)` with number of elements in X_train?

Comment: `print(X_train.shape)` will show you the shape of `X_train`.